# Opening a local file in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, groovlet

I want to use a `File` object to read a local file in the same directory as a groovlet. However, using a relative path to the file (either `"example.txt"` or `"./example.txt"`) doesn't do the trick. If I give it an absolute path (e.g., `"/example.txt"`), then it works.

Is there any way to get the working directory or context path of the groovlet programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new File("${request.getContextPath()}/example.txt")
```

Comment: Great! But what I was actually going for is `getRealPath('/')`. Your answer pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!